# Enviar datos encriptados desde codigo VB.Net a My.Settings con AES256 Base64 SHA512

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, vb, encriptación

Comunidad, estoy intentando ingresar los datos a detallar en `My.Settings`, guardarlos y `masterKey` que tiene la clave maestra desaparecerá luego para guardarse encriptada para cuando se lo necesite, todos los datos se encriptan bien, se envían y guardan en la tabla `TB_Registrarse` de la base SQLite. El problema es que o no se envían, no se guardan o algo del código está interfiriendo este proceso hacia `My.Settings`. A continuación, les dispongo el código en VB.Net donde se envían los datos:

```vb
Imports AppESTEMATI.My.MySettings
Imports AppESTEMATI.ModulatingConfiguration
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.Xml

Private Sub btnRegistrarse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrarse.Click
    Dim APLICATION As String = Me.cboAplicaciones.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim NOMBRES As String = Me.txtNombreUser.Text
    Dim APELLIDOS As String = Me.txtApellidoUser.Text
    Dim DIRECCION As String = Me.txtDomicilioUser.Text
    Dim TELEFONO As Int64 = Val(Me.txtPhoneUser.Text)
    Dim EMAIL As String = Me.txtEmailUser.Text
    Dim CONTRASENA As String = Me.txtPass.Text
    Dim REIT_CONTRAS As String = Me.txtPassword.Text
    Dim FECHA As Date = Date.Now
    Dim oportunidades As Integer = 0
    Dim click As ButtonState = ButtonState.Pushed

    ' Verificar si los TextBox están llenos
    If click = True And oportunidades = 1 And Me.cboAplicaciones.Text = "" Or Me.cboAplicaciones.Text <> "AppESTEMATI" Or Me.txtNombreUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtApellidoUser.Text = "" Or
    Me.txtDomicilioUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPhoneUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPass.Text = "" Or Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Por favor, complete todos los campos antes de registrar.", "Campos vacíos. 1ra Oportunidad", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Me.cboAplicaciones.Focus()
    Else
        ' Generar claves y vector de inicialización
        Dim aes As Aes = Aes.Create()
        aes.GenerateKey()
        aes.GenerateIV()

        ' Convertir las claves y el IV a cadenas base64
        Dim keyBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key)
        Dim ivBase64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV)

        ' Encriptar las claves y el IV antes de guardarlas en My.Settings
        ' Clave maestra para encriptar las claves
        Dim masterKey As String = "ThisIsASampleMasterKey1234567890"
        Dim keyEncrypted As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(keyBase64, masterKey)
        Dim ivEncrypted As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(ivBase64, masterKey)
        Dim masterKeyEncrypted As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(masterKey, masterKey)
        ' Guardar las claves encriptadas en My.Settings
        My.Settings.claveAES = keyEncrypted
        My.Settings.vectorAES = ivEncrypted
        My.Settings.masterKey = masterKeyEncrypted
        My.Settings.Save()
        'Desaparecer la clave original
        masterKey = Nothing
        ' Encriptar la contraseña antes de almacenarla en la base de datos
        Dim emailEncriptado As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(EMAIL, keyEncrypted)
        Dim contrasenaEncriptada As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(CONTRASENA, keyEncrypted)
        Dim reit_contrasEncriptada As String = ModulatingConfiguration.Encrypt(REIT_CONTRAS, keyEncrypted)

        ' Insertar usuario en la base de datos
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If

        Try
            Using transaction As SQLiteTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
                Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO TB_Registrarse (APLICATION, NOMBRES, APELLIDOS, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, EMAIL, CONTRASENA, REIT_CONTRAS, FECHA) VALUES (@APLICATION, @NOMBRES, @APELLIDOS, @DIRECCION, @TELEFONO, @EMAIL, @CONTRASENA, @REIT_CONTRAS, @FECHA)"
                Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(query, conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APLICATION", APLICATION)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRES", NOMBRES)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDOS", APELLIDOS)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRECCION", DIRECCION)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEFONO", TELEFONO)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", emailEncriptado)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRASENA", contrasenaEncriptada)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REIT_CONTRAS", reit_contrasEncriptada)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHA", FECHA)

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    transaction.Commit()

                    MessageBox.Show("Usuario registrado correctamente.", "Registro Exitoso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error al registrar usuario: " & ex.Message, "Error de Registro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal secretKey As String) As String
    Dim encryptedPassword As String = Nothing
    Dim keyBytes() As Byte

    Using sha512 As New SHA512Managed()
        keyBytes = sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey))
    End Using

    Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
    algorithm.Key = keyBytes.Take(algorithm.KeySize \ 8).ToArray() ' Ajustar la longitud de la clave
    algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

    Using outputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        Using cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor()
            Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(outputStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Dim inputBuffer() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)
                cryptoStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)
            End Using
        End Using

        encryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(outputStream.ToArray())
    End Using

    Return encryptedPassword
End Function

Public Function Decrypt(ByVal encryptedBytes As String, ByVal secretKey As String) As String
    Dim plainText As String = Nothing
    Dim keyBytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)

    Using sha512 As New SHA512Managed()
        Dim keyHash As Byte() = sha512.ComputeHash(keyBytes)

        Using inputStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedBytes))
            Dim algorithm As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
            algorithm.Key = keyHash
            algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
            algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

            Using cryptoTransform As ICryptoTransform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor()
                Using cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(inputStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                    Using reader As New StreamReader(cryptoStream)
                        plainText = reader.ReadToEnd()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return plainText
End Function
```